# Determine the function to be injective when $f: \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, (x,y) \mapsto x+y \sqrt{p}$ and p prime

Tags: linear-algebra

In an earlier exercise I prooved, that $\sqrt{p} \in \mathbb{R} $\ $ \mathbb{Q} $ if p prime. This seems to be a mayor help to proof the injectivity of $f$.

Now when we have:

$x+y \sqrt{p} = x'+y' \sqrt{p}$

I can conlude the following:

$x \ne y'\sqrt{p}$, else x would be irrational, same the other way around ($x' \ne y\sqrt{p}$), if they were equal $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$.

But I don't get, why $y = y'$ and $x = x'$.

Hints are very appreciated!

Comment: Observe that "else $\;x\;$ would be rational" seems to make no sense: $\;x\;$  **is rational by assumption**...and the same is true for $\;y\;$

Answer (score 1):

First, suppose $\;y\neq y'\;$ , then

$$x+y\sqrt p=x'+y'\sqrt p\implies (y-y')\sqrt p=x'-x\implies\sqrt p=\frac{x'-x}{y-y'}\in\Bbb Q$$

contradiction. Thus, it must be $\;y=y'\;$ , but then

$$\require{cancel}x+\cancel{y\sqrt p}=x'+\cancel{y\sqrt p}\implies x=x'$$

and we're done.